# Dropdownlist.selectedItem.text in Dropdownlist not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am populating the value from the DB table to a dropdown Field, but when it is getting bound to the drop-down list in the screen the exact value is getting bound, but 2 times (ie. Duplicate value is getting bound) in the drop-down list along with the original Value.

```
if (ddlhour.Items.Contains(ddlhour.Items.FindByValue(time[0].ToString())))
{
    ddlhour.SelectedItem.Text = time[0].ToString();
}
```

In the `SelectedItem.Text` the value is getting duplicated .
Can anyone help me solve the issue?

Where in `time[0]`, there is a Text from the DB table.

Comment: check your sql query for fetching data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
                if (ddlhour.Items.Contains(ddlhour.Items.FindByValue(time[0].ToString())))
                {
                    ddlhour.Items.FindByValue(time[0].ToString()).Selected = true;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

**FindBYText**

```
int index = ddlhour.Items.IndexOf(ddlhour.Items.FindByText("Others"));
//index = 1
if (index != -1) {
    ddlhour.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

**FindBy Value**

```
int j = ddlhour.Items.IndexOf(ddlhour.Items.FindByValue("Others"));
if (j != -1) {
    ddlhour.SelectedIndex = j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `selectedValue`

```
  ddlhour.SelectedValue = time[0].ToString();
```

`ddlhour.SelectedItem.Text` changes the text of selected item